# JMockit mock methods of the target class

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

I am new to JMockit. How can I mock method2() while writing tests for method1() using **Expectations** or any better approach. I used expectation to mock dependency classes.

```
public class A {

Dependency dep = new Dependency();
public int method1(int val){
    //some business logic
    //....
    //.....
    dep.someMethod();
    int ret = method2(val);
    return ret;
}

public int method2(int val) {
    //some business logic
    //....
    //.....
    return val;
}
```

}

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: If I don't do that how can complete unit test for method1(). Is there any other way?

Comment: test whatever happens in method2 for method1 as well.

Comment: In my actual class, I am calling the methods of the same class itself to acheive some output. So when I try to write unit tests for method1() it was throwing errors as I am not passing real values to method2(). And this method2() internally calling too many others methods of different classes.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your last comment.

Comment: in your test for method1 you have to test the functionality of method2 as well. You may want to share your test setup and test assertions between the tests for both methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177753/discussion-between-a8989-and-luk2302).

Comment: Actually, method2() has too many dependencies with other classes. So I am able to mock dependent classes but some classes I am not able to mock using @Injectable annotation that's I was thinking to mock the method2() itself so that I can avoid mocking all it's dependent classess.

Comment: you have to test method2 anyway. so mocking it because it is too complex does not help much.

Comment: I was thinking any approach is there because for now, I don't need to test method2. anyhow as you said it's hard to mock method2 so I will try to test method2().

Comment: Actually, you can easily test `method1` while mocking `method2` by *partially* mocking the class. However, that's generally a bad idea. The only legitimate things to be mocking here would be those dependencies that `method2` use. Personally, I avoid mocking as much as possible, since it's not conducive to good tests, and it often gets used as a way to avoid fixing design issues in the code under test (which seems to be the case here: a) calling a public method from another instead of factoring common code into a private method; b) having too many dependencies in a single class).

Comment: Yes you are right @Rogério. The `method2` has too many dependencies and those dependencies again dependent on others too. Due to this, I am not able to mock some of the dependencies so trying to mock `method2`. Actually, these classes were written by others very long back and now I got a task to write unit tests. I can't redesign the classes as there is no enough time in my hands. Looking for an alternative approach. BTW how to mock `method2` _partially_ the class under test.

Comment: See the section on [Partial mocking](http://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/Mocking.html#partial), in the Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Create Mockup of method2 and return based on the test case you testing for.

```
new MockUp<A>() {

            @Mock
           int method2(int val) // no access modifier required
            {
                return yourRequiredOutput;
            }
}
 new Expectations() {

            {
                depMock.someMethod();
            }
        };
```